# How can I query users with a specific Job title?

Tags: feature-request, support, data-explorer

I'm looking for a query which can be used to search a user by their title. I have tried looking into the Users table but the Job title/position column isn't present there.
It's the one highlighted below in red.

[image: Example]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. That field is only present (or at least *populated*) in the Stack Overflow database and not on the other sites. So SEDE won't be able to give you these results.

There's a [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232) which tells you which fields *are* available, but Job Title isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel. Can we request a feature in SEDE ?

Comment: Sure: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+data-explorer I'm not sure if this one would fly; no site-specific features have been added before.